# Remove context variable in Node.js app before sending to IBM Watson Assistant

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have this code in Node.js. I need to change the value of my context property in the response to IBM Watson Assistant, but this is not working:

```
if(response.context.email){
      response.context.email=null;
}
```

What is the form to change the value of context property?

Comment: Are you trying to change the value of "response.context.email" or "response.context"

Comment: If you want to just delete the property off of response.context, you can do "delete response.context.email"

Comment: How can I change the value from Node.JS?

Comment: The way you're doing it should be changing the value IF there is already an email property on response.context. Have you tried doing a console.log(response.context) to see if it is even going into the if statement?

Comment: Yes, exist. In watson assistant I put the variable "email" like "true". I try to change the value to "null" but not working

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to either use `"null"` as value or, better `None`.

You are on the client side. Only the values that you send to Watson Assistant are considered for further processing. If you change the reponse object (JSON object) to not contain any email property, it should not be available on the server side for Watson Assistant.

For manipulating the JSON object in Node.js you could look into using [Object methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). This helps to delete or add properties to the response structure.